# How to organize RoR server to produce some side work, without blocking main REST functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message-queue

It's needed to make http requests to appropriate urls each 30 minute. Currently my RoR server handles bunch of simple routes, and I don't wanna my sending service to blocks main routing, in other words - make requests from queue only when there is no other job. I have no idea how Ruby handles threads(came from js world) and don't want to dig deep, just wanna know should I care about it or not? Thanks.

Comment: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: thank you, will explore it.